# Как правильно сверстать интерфейс под Android

Tags: android, вёрстка

Задача - разработать графический пользовательский интерфейс для многотонального генератора сигналов. Интерфейс должен соответствовать критериям:

1. Окно приложения содержит 2 вкладки, переключаться между которыми можно свайпом по экрану.
2. На каждой вкладке присутствуют три визуально разделенные друг от друга группы элементов для настройки тона генерируемого сигнала.

Я пытался решить задачу следующим образом:

- создал фрагмент с возможностью настройки параметров одного тона;
- создал фрагмент, содержащий три FragmentContainerView для настройки тона;
- ну, далее просто создал Adapter возвращающий экземпляры второго по списку фрагмента, TabLayout и ViewPager2, прописал логику, к работе вкладок претензий нет.

К сожалению, данное решение не позволяет получить экземпляры фрагментов настройки параметров тона (которых по 3 в каждой вкладке). Из-за этого я не могу получить доступ к свойствам и методам этих фрагментов, как следствие, не вижу, что пользователь в них выбрал и не могу корректировать их содержимое из кода.

Вследствие этого возникает вопрос: как же правильно решить мою задачу? Как создать интерфейс, удовлетворяющий моим требованиям и обладающий возможностью взаимодействовать с программой? Спасибо!
[image: Требуемый интерфейс на мобильном телефоне]
[image: Фрагмент для настройки параметров тона]
[image: Фрагмент с тремя FragmentContainerView]

Comment: "не могу получить доступ" -- откуда? Мне кажется вопрос по архитектуре, а не по верстке.

Comment: >"не могу получить доступ" -- откуда? Вообще ниоткуда! Вот на второй фрагмент я добавил три FragmentContainer, но не могу считать введенные пользователем данные из editText и спиннеров, например. Ну в общем, я описал подробно проблему в вопросе, не знаю, что можно уточнить

Comment: Т.е. сам фрагмент не может получить значения из собственного editText и spinner? Тогда код в студию, зачем эти все картинки?